# Populating a ListView Inside a Tab Control in VB 2010

Tags: vb.net

I am pretty new in Visual Basic. I have a tab control in my form and inside it I put a listview. What I wanted to do is populate the listview everytime I clicked on each tab. But I don't know how to do it.

Can anyone please help me?

Here is the bit of my code

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub PopulateRecords()
        Dim TSR As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim STRSQL As String = ""
        STRSQL &= "SELECT * from Records " & vbCrLf
        STRSQL &= "WHERE (Customer_name like '" & TextBox1.Text & "%' or Item_name like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%' or Item_code like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%' or Price like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%' or Qty like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%' or Total_price like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%' or Date_started like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%' or Date_finish like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%')" & vbCrLf
        STRSQL &= "order by Customer_name, Item_name" & vbCrLf
        TSR.Open(STRSQL, CNN, 1, 3)
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        While Not TSR.EOF
            ListView1.Items.Add(TSR.Fields("Customer_name").Value)
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(TSR.Fields("Item_name").Value)
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(TSR.Fields("Item_code").Value)
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(TSR.Fields("Price").Value)
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(TSR.Fields("Qty").Value)
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(TSR.Fields("Total_price").Value)
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(TSR.Fields("Date_started").Value)
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(TSR.Fields("Date_finish").Value)
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(TSR.Fields("ID").Value)
            TSR.MoveNext()
        End While
        TSR.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TabPage1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabPage1.Click
        Call PopulateRecords()
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question where your current implementation is falling short of your goal - could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Sorry about that. Well the problem now is everytime I clicked on each tab my listview is still empty. Hope you now understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try responding to the [SelectedIndexChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) on the parent (the TabControl). This is fired when the user moves between tabs.  TabPage.Click is fired when the page itself is clicked upon - not when the tab is changed to.

Comment: Glad to help, Celine - enjoy your .Net programming!

Answer (score 0):

Use the **SelectedIndexChanged** event of your tab control.

```
    private sub tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(Byval sender as System.Object, _
            Byval e as System.EventArgs) Handles tabControl.SelectedIndexChanged
    {
        PopulateRecords()
    }
```

You can also identify what tab page you are viewing by:

```
    byval page as TabPage = tabControl.TabPages(tabControl.SelectedIndex)
```

Hope this helps =D

Comment: Hi again. I now have two tabs in my tab control and each tab has different listview. When i use the SelectedIndexChanged of the tabcontrol only the tab page 1 listview is populated. the listview in tab page 2 which is supposed to populate another set of info is left empty.

Comment: You can use **SelectedIndexChanged** event and determine what tab page the user is viewing by **tabControl.SelectedIndex**. So when the selected index is 1, call **PopulateRecordsForTabPage1**; if selected index is 2, call **PopulateRecordsForTabPage2**. By the way, do you have separate functions to populate each listview?

Comment: Yeah I do have a separate function for that. I'll try what you just suggested and let you know how it works. Thank you so much.